# C# .NET HTTP Client SendAsnyc function not working the same on MAUI as on Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I have a simple function which does a GET request using HTTPClient SendAsync.

I’m in the process of moving to MAUI and I’ve ported this across from our Xamarin app. This function returns correctly when running with Xamarin, but with MAUI it appears that the JSON payload data is not going through to our WordPress API correctly and the API responds with 400s or 403s.

I am testing on an Android emulator (API 33).

The code is as follows;

```
    // at class initialisation
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
    };

    httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut)
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");

    // further down the class
    public async Task<string> Get<T>(T item, string path, bool https = false)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        var requestMethod = "http://";

        if (https)
        {
            requestMethod = "https://";
        }

        var serverString = requestMethod + path;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(serverString),
            Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        HttpContent Content = response.Content;
        var json = await Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        response.Dispose();
        return json;
    }
```

For example, here is a simple call to the Posts endpoint, requesting a list of blog posts;

https://[website_address]/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

The JSON data is as follows;

{
"context":"view",
"id":0,
"page":1,
"per_page":100,
"search":"",
"order":"desc",
"orderby":"date",
"status":"publish",
"sticky":false
}

On Xamarin the result is (blog post data returned as expected):
[image: XAMARIN]

On MAUI, the result is (403, API is assuming I am trying to create a blog post?!):
[image: MAUI]

Additionally, I’ve tested a “normal” Get operation and it works fine (i.e. a HTTPClient.Get). Hopefully someone out there with a larger brain knows why, thanks in advance!

Comment: are u using the same code to call the api in maui

Comment: Hi @user123456, yes the entire class is the same.

Comment: How does your server authenticate users?  A 403 means an auth failure

Comment: that what i was wondering in Maui, you need token @Jason

Comment: Authentication is done at the start of the app, and the token is assigned to the HTTP client after that process. Authentication is not the issue at this point because normal Get operations are working correctly (for example pulling down profile data works as expected), I believe it is something to do with how the payload is being sent but can't work out what it could be. Sometimes it can be a 400 error, depending on which endpoint I call. It only happens in this scenario where I'm trying to send some JSON data as part of a Get

Comment: are u sending json

Comment: If you're getting 40x then the server is likely not getting the auth headers. I would look at how and when you're giving the auth token to the `HttpClient` and verify that it's actually going through.

Comment: you need to look in the logs at the actual request received by your service and compare the working and non working requests

Comment: Side note: instead of calling `Dispose` explicitly you should have a `using`. This goes for the request and response objects.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone, after a lot of searching and trying different things, I came across a post on GitHub, it seems that the request is being changed from a GET to a POST when it goes out (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8199). This explains the errors that I am getting. At this point I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Does this issue only occur on Android platform?

Comment: Hey @GuangyuBai-MSFT, I've only managed to get the Android version of my app running at this point so I cannot confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their input. After trying various approaches with the HTTPClient/HttpRequestMessage combination without any luck, I manage to get it working using the RestSharp library where I was able to execute a GetAsync with the JSON data as part of the parameters of the request.

```
    public async Task<string> Get<T>(T item, string path, bool https = false)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        var requestMethod = "http://";

        if (https)
        {
            requestMethod = "https://";
        }

        var serverString = requestMethod + path;

        var options = new RestClientOptions
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(serverString),
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
        };
        var client = new RestClient(options);

        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Method = Method.Get,
            Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(timeOut),
        };
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthorisationToken);
        request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
```

Hopefully this helps anyone out there who comes across this strange issue.